# Why is the output voltage (without capacitor) of a boost converter seen as a perfect square wave?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, waveform, buck-boost

I am trying to learn about boost converters, but I don't understand why the images of the voltage output always seems to be like a square wave PWM. I understand that assuming perfect inductors, the current wave form would be a sawtooth and the voltage would be a square wave with peaks of Vs and dips of Vs - Vo. I get that this leads to a square wave across the inductor because V=I di/dt, but then I conflict myself with the output wave form. If the sum of all voltages in a loop were to be 0, then I get the essence the output voltage does not change during when the switch is off. On the other hand, the loop current is clearly changing, and since the load is resistive, then the voltage would have to vary proportionally.

Comment: Please show an image that you are referring to.

Comment: Have done, hope it helps @KevinWhite

Comment: I'm sorry @Georgekirby but you can't and shouldn't make wholesale changes to a question once it has received answers. So, I've rolled it back to how it was originally because it then ties in with the answers given. If you want to raise a brand new question like what your modifications were then I'm happy to answer. The clear crux of the original question was about using a boost converter **without** an output capacitor.

Comment: @Andyaka okay ill make a new question and specifically add requirments

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answers that are useful and accept the answer that is most useful (for this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original question:

> Why is the output voltage (without capacitor) of a boost converter seen as a perfect square wave?

The output voltage of a boost converter **must** be across a capacitor, because a boost converter **by definition** has a capacitor connected across its output terminals, which is where the load is connected.  This capacitor has a very important role to play: it receives the current from the inductor when the switch is OFF, and continues to supply current to the load when the switch is ON (when the inductor current is flowing from the input voltage source into the switch).

Without that capacitor, then this is no longer a **boost converter**, it is something else.  Also, without that capacitor, there is nothing to limit the voltage across the switching device (transistor) when it turns OFF, and if this was to be implemented in a real-world circuit then it would often result in the destruction of the switching device.  The behaviour of this **non-boost** circuit then becomes highly dependent on exactly what the load is: is the load a capacitor, a resistor, or an inductor, or a combination of these, or something else entirely?

The output voltage of a boost converter should ideally be constant, ie: a non-zero DC value that is not changing with time.  In reality, on a scope it will appear as a DC value with a small amount of ripple.

This may be helpful:
[Inductive kickback](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/398922/341959)

Comment: Thank you, i improved my question to make it clearer,  but you point raised something i didnt know about before either, why would there be a really high voltage without the capacitor if there was a resitive load?  From the link you sent it seems there were no other path for the inductor charge to go one the swith is opended, but in the boost scenario there would be through the resistor? Or is your point more for in the event there is no load attached? Thanks

Comment: @Georgekirby  Hi, yes, if there is a resistor instead of a capacitor at the output, then in theory the voltage at the output will be limited to V = I * R, where I is the current in the inductor at the moment the switch is turned off.  However, in practise, there will always be some unavoidable **parasitic** inductance in series with that R, meaning that in practice the voltage will be **much** higher than predicted by the simple V = I * R formula.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why is the output voltage (without capacitor) of a boost converter
> seen as a perfect square wave?*

Without an output capacitor, the main switching transistor is (more than likely) going into avalanche voltage overload and, this is not a good thing.

If you had a resistive load connected, this can prevent the avalanche overload but, the output voltage would not be anything like a square wave. Hence, I suspect the former.

Comment: Thank you, i reworded my question in hopes to make what i wondered more clearer

Comment: I'm sorry @Georgekirby but you **can't and shouldn't** make wholesale changes to a question once it has received answers. So, I've rolled it back to how it was originally because it then ties in with the answers given. If you want to raise a **brand new** question like what your modifications were then I'm happy to answer. The clear crux of this current question was about using a boost converter without an output capacitor.